# Web Scraping - Using R, Error in bind_rows_(x, .id)

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping

My output data should be similar to the image I've attached

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvWqa.png)

I have used following code but I'm getting an error

```
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Can not automatically convert from character to integer in column "Runs"
```

I have used following sample code

```
require(rvest)
require(tidyverse)

urls <- c("http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/326016.html?class=2;filter=advanced;floodlit=1;innings_number=1;orderby=start;result=1;template=results;type=batting;view=match",
"http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/326016.html?class=2;filter=advanced;floodlit=2;innings_number=2;orderby=start;result=1;template=results;type=batting;view=match",
"http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/326016.html?class=2;filter=advanced;floodlit=1;innings_number=1;orderby=start;result=2;template=results;type=batting;view=match",
"http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/326016.html?class=2;filter=advanced;floodlit=1;innings_number=2;orderby=start;result=2;template=results;type=batting;view=match",
"http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/326016.html?class=2;filter=advanced;floodlit=2;innings_number=1;orderby=start;result=2;template=results;type=batting;view=match",
"http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/326016.html?class=2;filter=advanced;floodlit=2;innings_number=2;orderby=start;result=2;template=results;type=batting;view=match"
)

extra_cols <- list(tibble("Team"="IND","Player"="B.Kumar","won"=1,"lost"=0,"D"=1,"D/N"=0,"innings"=1,"Format"="ODI"),
                   tibble("Team"="IND","Player"="B.Kumar","won"=1,"lost"=0,"D"=0,"D/N"=1,"innings"=2,"Format"="ODI"),
                   tibble("Team"="IND","Player"="B.Kumar","won"=0,"lost"=1,"D"=1,"D/N"=0,"innings"=1,"Format"="ODI"),
                   tibble("Team"="IND","Player"="B.Kumar","won"=0,"lost"=1,"D"=1,"D/N"=0,"innings"=2,"Format"="ODI"),
                   tibble("Team"="IND","Player"="B.Kumar","won"=0,"lost"=1,"D"=0,"D/N"=1,"innings"=1,"Format"="ODI"),
                   tibble("Team"="IND","Player"="B.Kumar","won"=0,"lost"=1,"D"=0,"D/N"=1,"innings"=2,"Format"="ODI")
)

doc <- map(urls, read_html) %>% 
  map(html_node, ".engineTable:nth-child(5)")



keep <- map_lgl(doc, ~class(.) != "xml_missing")  #### condition to exclude when web urls return "NO Records"###

table<-map(doc[keep], html_table, fill = TRUE) %>% 
  map2_df(extra_cols[keep], cbind)
```

Comment: The problem lies in the last operation `map2_df`. If you simply swap `map2_df` with `map2` it works.

Comment: @G.Gamba I want in dataframe, it contains mixed data types. Example : list(Bat1 = c("0*", "1*", "DNB", "DNB", "DNB", "DNB",  :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the "-" sometimes in the `Runs` column.
So when there is no "-" `html_table` interprets this as integer column,
if there is a "-" its interpreted as character.

Obviously "-" should be interpreted as `NA`. This can be achieved by `type_convert` as follows:

```
table<-map(doc[keep], html_table, fill = TRUE) %>% 
  map(type_convert, na = c("", NA, "-")) %>% 
  map2_df(extra_cols[keep], cbind)
```

The `na = c("", NA, "-")` maps "-" to NA.